# Coded UI tests - run multiple tests

Tags: coded-ui-tests, data-driven-tests

I have following problem.

I need to run 10 tests in a row - driven by excel workbook. Each row is one test case.

My problem is when I add the following line:

```
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc", 
            "Dsn=Excel Files;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};dbq=|DataDirectory|\\RecordedSteps\\Input.xlsx;defaultdir=.;driverid=790;maxbuffersize=2048;pagetimeout=5;readonly=true", 
            "List1$", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]
```

It iterates over excel workbook in one test case.

What I need is to read one line of excel worksheet, fill input and complete test case and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The `[DataSoure(...)]` and `[TestMethod]` attributes apply to the method that immediately follows them. The `[DataSoure(...)]` attribute instructs Coded UI to run the method a number of times; once for each set of data, eg for each row in a spreadsheet.

To run 10 different tests requires 10 methods each having a `[TestMethod]` attribute. Any of these methods can be data driven, but will need their own `[DataSource(...)]` attributes.